# Spark 2.3 Tree Error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, python-3.6, py4j

This query is based on one step further from the query in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530679/spark-2-3-asynceventqueue-error-and-warning). In this scenario, I add 1 or 2 more columns to be processed, Spark throws an ERROR by printing the physical plan of queries.

It says, **Resolved attribute(s) fnlwgt_bucketed#152530 missing** which is untrue, as if I run the same code on less than 3 columns where this is one column, it works like a charm, so I can clearly assume it is not a bug in my query or code.

Is it then a out of memory error? As I think, internally, since there are many registered tables on memory, they're getting deleted due to overflow of data and getting deleted, this is totally my assumption. Any insight on this? Did anyone of you face any issue like this?

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o21.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) fnlwgt_bucketed#152530 missing from occupation#17,high_income#25,fnlwgt#13,education#14,marital-status#16,relationship#18,workclass#12,sex#20,id_num#10,native_country#24,race#19,education-num#15,hours-per-week#23,age_bucketed#152432,capital-loss#22,age#11,capital-gain#21,fnlwgt_bucketed#99009 in operator !Project [id_num#10, age#11, workclass#12, fnlwgt#13, education#14, education-num#15, marital-status#16, occupation#17, relationship#18, race#19, sex#20, capital-gain#21, capital-loss#22, hours-per-week#23, native_country#24, high_income#25, age_bucketed#152432, fnlwgt_bucketed#152530, if (isnull(cast(hours-per-week#23 as double))) null else if (isnull(cast(hours-per-week#23 as double))) null else if (isnull(cast(hours-per-week#23 as double))) null else if (isnull(cast(hours-per-week#23 as double))) null else if (isnull(cast(hours-per-week#23 as double))) null else if (isnull(cast(hours-per-week#23 as double))) null else if (isnull(cast(hours-per-week#23 as double))) null else if (isnull(cast(hours-per-week#23 as double))) null else if (isnull(cast(hours-per-week#23 as double))) null else if (isnull(cast(hours-per-week#23 as double))) null else if (isnull(cast(hours-per-week#23 as double))) null else if (isnull(cast(hours-per-week#23 as double))) null else if (isnull(cast(hours-per-week#23 as double))) null else UDF:bucketizer_0(cast(hours-per-week#23 as double)) AS hours-per-week_bucketed#152299]. Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: fnlwgt_bucketed. Please check if the right attribute(s) are used.;;
Project [id_num#10, age#11, workclass#12, fnlwgt#13, education#14, education-num#15, marital-status#16, occupation#17, relationship#18, race#19, sex#20, capital-gain#21, capital-loss#22, hours-per-week#23, native_country#24, high_income#25, age_bucketed#48257, fnlwgt_bucketed#99009, hours-per-week_bucketed#152299, age_bucketed_WoE#152431, WoE#152524 AS fnlwgt_bucketed_WoE#152529]
+- Join Inner, (fnlwgt_bucketed#99009 = fnlwgt_bucketed#152530)
   :- SubqueryAlias bucketed
   :  +- SubqueryAlias a
   :     +- Project [id_num#10, age#11, workclass#12, fnlwgt#13, education#14, education-num#15, marital-status#16, occupation#17, relationship#18, race#19, sex#20, capital-gain#21, capital-loss#22, hours-per-week#23, native_country#24, high_income#25, age_bucketed#48257, fnlwgt_bucketed#99009, hours-per-week_bucketed#152299, WoE#152426 AS age_bucketed_WoE#152431]
   :        +- Join Inner, (age_bucketed#48257 = age_bucketed#152432)
   :           :- SubqueryAlias bucketed
   :           :  +- SubqueryAlias a
   :           :     +- Project [id_num#10, age#11, workclass#12, fnlwgt#13, education#14, education-num#15, marital-status#16, occupation#17, relationship#18, race#19, sex#20, capital-gain#21, capital-loss#22, hours-per-week#23, native_country#24, high_income#25, age_bucketed#48257, fnlwgt_bucketed#99009, if (isnull(cast(hours-per-week#23 as double))) null else if (isnull(cast(hours-per-week#23 as double))) null else if (isnull(cast(hours-per-week#23 as double))) null else UDF:bucketizer_0(cast(hours-per-week#23 as double)) AS hours-per-week_bucketed#152299]
   :           :        +- Project [id_num#10, age#11, workclass#12, fnlwgt#13, education#14, education-num#15, marital-status#16, occupation#17, relationship#18, race#19, sex#20, capital-gain#21, capital-loss#22, hours-per-week#23, native_country#24, high_income#25, age_bucketed#48257, if (isnull(cast(fnlwgt#13 as double))) null else if (isnull(cast(fnlwgt#13 as double))) null else if (isnull(cast(fnlwgt#13 as double))) null else UDF:bucketizer_0(cast(fnlwgt#13 as double)) AS fnlwgt_bucketed#99009]
   :           :           +- Project [id_num#10, age#11, workclass#12, fnlwgt#13, education#14, education-num#15, marital-status#16, occupation#17, relationship#18, race#19, sex#20, capital-gain#21, capital-loss#22, hours-per-week#23, native_country#24, high_income#25, if (isnull(cast(age#11 as double))) null else if (isnull(cast(age#11 as double))) null else if (isnull(cast(age#11 as double))) null else UDF:bucketizer_0(cast(age#11 as double)) AS age_bucketed#48257]
   :           :              +- Relation[id_num#10,age#11,workclass#12,fnlwgt#13,education#14,education-num#15,marital-status#16,occupation#17,relationship#18,race#19,sex#20,capital-gain#21,capital-loss#22,hours-per-week#23,native_country#24,high_income#25] csv
   :           +- SubqueryAlias woe_table
```

And this continues.

Comment: It's very hard to help you debug if we cannot reproduce the error please create a minimum verifiable and complexe example so we can help ?